# How to access 2D array fields in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

-----problem solved, see the update 2 below----
I put all MySQL query results into a 2D array:

```
$suppDescription=mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($results);
$allSupplierInfo=array();

for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++){
    $allSupplierInfo[]=mysql_fetch_row($suppDescription);
}
```

But now I cannot access the $allSuppliersInfo fields.

```
 echo $allSupplierInfo[1][1]; // prints out 'Array'
 echo $allSupplierInfo[1]['id'];  //prints out nothing
```

What am I doing wrong?

------- UPDATE-----

**print_r($allSupplierInfo)** prints the following, so it looks like the loop is not working as I wanted it to:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>ID_A[1] => name_A [2] => Address_A[3] => Link_A ) ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>ID_A[1] => name_A [2] => Address_A[3] => Link_A ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>ID_B[1] => Name_B [2] => Address_B [3] => Link_B ) ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>ID_A[1] => name_A [2] => Address_A[3] => Link_A ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>ID_B[1] => Name_B [2] => Address_B [3] => Link_B ) [2] => Array ( [0] =>ID_C[1] => Name_C [2] => Address_C [3] => Link_C ) ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>ID_A[1] => name_A [2] => Address_A[3] => Link_A ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>ID_B[1] => Name_B [2] => Address_B [3] => Link_B ) [2] => Array ( [0] =>ID_C[1] => Name_C [2] => Address_C [3] => Link_C ) [3] => Array ( [0] =>ID_D[1] => Name_D [2] => Address_D [3] => Link_D ) ) 
    [4] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>ID_A[1] => name_A [2] => Address_A[3] => Link_A ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>ID_B[1] => Name_B [2] => Address_B [3] => Link_B ) [2] => Array ( [0] =>ID_C[1] => Name_C [2] => Address_C [3] => Link_C ) [3] => Array ( [0] =>ID_D[1] => Name_D [2] =>     Address_D [3] => Link_D ) [4] => Array ( [0] =>ID_E[1] => Name_E [2] => Address_E [3] => Address_E ) ) )
```

------ UPDATE 2-----
Using the while loop, as suggested by RiggsFolly, solved the problem and I can access the fields as I initially wanted. I still do not understand why the for loop I used did not loop as I thought it would - any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: print_r($allSupplierInfo) print this and see is this printing properly or not.

Comment: can you show me entire code.

Comment: May just be a typo on the question, but in the first block of code you have `$allSupplierInfo`, but on the echo, you have an extra `s` in the variable name `$allSuppliersInfo`

Comment: @JRichardSnape - that was indeed just typos, fixed and well spotted, thanks!
Also, added the result of print_r

Comment: Sorry Isabel you cannot change your question, you are supposed to ask a new one, or the original question and answers will be no use to others seeking help for similiar problems.

Comment: @RiggsFolly W\I can edit the updated question, which part do you mean? I did not think I was changing it, as I still want to know what I was doing wrong. I thought the fact that the while loop worked was helpful to mention.

Comment: Probably best to put the original error back in (using `$result` instead of `$suppDescription`), so that @RiggsFolly answer makes sense to anyone arriving here in 6 months time...  I think that's what is meant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused with your mysql result processing, you are using `$result` when checking for the number of rows returned but it should be `$suppDescription`.

This means that your for loop will not run as you will be getting 0 or probbaly `FALSE` as a response to `mysql_num_rows($suppDescription);`

```
$suppDescription=mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($suppDescription);
$allSupplierInfo=array();

for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++){
    $allSupplierInfo[]=mysql_fetch_row($suppDescription);
}
```

Also this is easier done with a `while loop`, then you just process whatever is returned and dont need to bother getting the number of rows.

```
$suppDescription=mysql_query($query);

$allSupplierInfo=array();

while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_row($suppDescription) ) {
    $allSupplierInfo[]=mysql_fetch_row($suppDescription);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Riggs, it was a typo in my code, I fetched the same rows twice using with two different variables, $results and $suppDescription. I fixed it but the problem did not change. I'll try the while loop you suggested, looks like my for loop did not loop the way I expected (I updated my original question to reflect that)